# failed to pass jquery array to php variable in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on this page (rolemanage.php), I have button when it clicked it will trigger the script to give the array data

button code (rolemanage.php) :

```
a href="<?= base_url('admin/roleaccess/') ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aksesModal" class="badge badge-warning aksesModal" data-id="<?= $r['id_lvl']; ?>" class="badge badge-warning">Akses</a>
```

onclick script (rolemanage.php)

```
$('.aksesModal').on('click', function() {

    const id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= base_url('admin/getMenuid'); ?>",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            var strData = JSON.stringify(data);                
        }
    }); });
```

so the variable data success get the array back from admin/getMenuid and the result arrays in console like this :

```
(1) […] ​ 0: Object { id: "4", menu: "Barang Habis Pakai" } ​ length: 1
```

then after that I tried to make that object to string using json.stringify in success: function

and the result like this :

```
[{"id":"3","menu":"Menu"}]
```

the question is : when I tried call strData in this page (rolemanage.php) using

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['strData']));
```

it shows undefined index strData.

how to get the strData value then ?

Comment: there's only a `$_POST['id']` sent to php. _Where_ exactly do you do the `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['strData']));` and where should it come from?

Comment: Using Ajax, you've just got the strDats value from your server into your page. Why are you then trying to access it through PHP, back on the server? That makes no sense logically. If there is some PHP code in your rolemanage page, that code ran when the page was first loaded, before it was sent to the browser. The Ajax call runs after the page was loaded, because it runs inside the browser. If you want to use the data returned by the Ajax call, you have to do that using JavaScript, not PHP. I suggest you get a better understanding of the lifecycle of a web page.

Comment: @ADyson im using codeigniter modals to get the result of the array, so I thought when ajax processing the url and get the array value back it can be passed again to php, thx for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

1. rolemanage.php runs
2. The HTTP server sends the result to the browser
3. The browser runs the JavaScript
4. roleaccess runs
5. The HTTP server sends the result to the browser
6. You can process the result with JavaScript

Ajax doesn't involve time travel. You can't change what happened at step 1 with data you don't get until step 4.

Do your processing with JavaScript in step 6 (and modify the DOM with the new data), or don't use Ajax and use a regular form submission instead.

Comment: thx for explaining the ajax, still learning this, before this answer I thought after ajax processing the url and passing back the array to rolemanage.php it can processed again to pass as php variable, so based on your answer the only way I can get array value is passing the variable via javascript to php variable right ? CMIIW

Comment: "passing the variable via javascript to php variable right" — that's more-or-less what Ajax is.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform anothere AJAX request in which you pass strData as parameter.

Furthermore, if you want to keep everything in the same file (rolemanage.php) you should write an if statement that checks whether strData exists or not and do something based on the result